How to wait after GCP/PubSub pull until all threads are done
I have below code which is yet to be tested
    @Bean("customtaskexecutor")
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("my-poller-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }


    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "myInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "200",maxMessagesPerPoll = "10",taskExecutor = "customtaskexecutor"))
    public MessageSource<Object> pubsubAdapter(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        log.info("Entering");
        PubSubMessageSource messageSource = new PubSubMessageSource(pubSubTemplate,  "subs");
        messageSource.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO_ACK);
        messageSource.setPayloadType(MyClass.class);
        messageSource.setBlockOnPull(true);
        log.info("Exiting");
        return messageSource;
    }

My Goal is that I pull say 5 messages, and they all go on the executor. Only after all 5 are done, I want the next batch to be pulled. I am unable to find any examples of that. I do not want my queue in JVM memory to keep getting overloaded.
@Artem Bilan, any help is appreciated.

I think the PubSub client library has an internal queue. Not sure, but it could explain your misunderstanding.
